# C# WPF binding json data with checkbox into a listbox

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I have a project in C# with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF).
My json is like this

```
[
  {
    "question": "SelOneRad",
    "text": "This is a Select One - Radio question.",
    "type": "Select (Radio Button)",
    "rows": [
      {
        "text": "Option 1",
        "checked": false,
        "fields": "1",
        "column": "SelOneRad"
      },
      {
        "text": "Option 2",
        "checked": false,
        "fields": "2",
        "column": "SelOneRad"
      },
      {
        "text": "Option 3",
        "checked": false,
        "fields": "3",
        "column": "SelOneRad"
      },
      {
        "text": "Others, please specify: ",
        "checked": false,
        "fields": "4",
        "column": "SelOneRad"
      },
      {
        "text": "None ",
        "checked": false,
        "fields": "5",
        "column": "SelOneRad"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For the rows: i need to have a checkbox and the name from the field text.

I'm new in WPF.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code from your project? What specific issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: You should create a class and deserialize your JSON into that class. Then have a Property of that class in your ViewModel and bind to that.

Comment: I dont have a code yet but I know already how to bind json data into a list box . the problem is I want that each text in rows field will have a checkbox.

Comment: Do you currently have any xaml?

Comment: for the checkbox and the text not yet . for this field only "question": "SelOneRad",
    "text": "This is a Select One - Radio question.",
    "type":

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, if it's wrong could you expand on your explanation.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding rows}"> //the JSON array you want to bind to
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding text}/> //JSON array's fields here (rows.text)
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding checked}/> //JSON array's fields here (rows.checked)
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If you want to create a class based off your `JSON` you can go to `Edit` > `Paste Special` > `Paste JSON as Classes` to do this you must be in a .cs file